# Executing TeraData codes using SAS function

Tags: function, sas, teradata

I have a question about executing the `year()` function in TeraData from SAS. For example, when executing the code below, I will get the error message below the codes. Is there a way to execute the `year()` function besides using the year function in SAS after the table is created from TeraData?

```
 select * from connection to teradata (
      select customer_id
           , year(date)
      from base.customers a
  );
```

```
ERROR: Teradata execute: Syntax error: expected something between ',' and the 'year' keyword
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error because there is no `YEAR` function in Teradata. Instead you can use `Extract()`:

```
 select * from connection to teradata (
      select customer_id
           , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)
      from base.customers a
  );
```